# How to do subtract from two textbox on textchanged event in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I am new in vb.net. I have two text box. txtCash, txtCreditAmt.
look at the code sample. it is working but the problem i am facing problem when i am going to type decimal number. when i tried to type 14 is okay but when i tried to type 14.98 it is typing 1498. very surprisingly point(.) not accepting at all. in vb6 same type of code are working fine. How i can solve this issue?

```
    Private Sub txtCash_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtCash.TextChanged
    txtCreditAmt.Text = Val(lblTotalAmt.Text) - Val(txtCash.Text)
    txtCashTenered.Text = Val(txtCash.Text) + Val(txtCreditAmt.Text)
    SendKeys.Send("{End}")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful of the `CultureInfo` as in some regions numbers are written:

**123,456,789.00**

But in other regions:

**123,456,789 00**

For more information you can use either the `CurrentCulture` or the `InvariantCulture`

Thus I would propose something like this:

```
Private Sub txtCash_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtCash.TextChanged
    Dim WantedCulture As Globalization.CultureInfo = Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    txtCreditAmt.Text = Decimal.Parse(lblTotalAmt.Text, WantedCulture) - Decimal.Parse(txtCash.Text, WantedCulture)
    txtCashTenered.Text = Decimal.Parse(txtCash.Text, WantedCulture) + Decimal.Parse(txtCreditAmt.Text, WantedCulture)
    SendKeys.Send("{End}")
End Sub
```

[CultureInfo MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use globalization namespace, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator(v=vs.110).aspx. But for some reason, sometimes i usually solve this by using `Replace(txtCash.Text, ".", ",")` or `Replace(txtCash.Text, ",", ".")` depending on how is configured your regional settings.

Comment: Regional Settings is always preferred. This comes from the fact that if someones laptop or computer is running a Windows version in different language and regional settings even the replacing wont work.